# Как добавить класс hide?

Tags: javascript, css

```js
const textNumber = parseInt(document.querySelector('.first').textContent.match(/\d+/));
const text = document.querySelector('.first');
document.querySelector('.btnForm').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    const inputNumber = document.getElementById('outInput').value;
    const inputNumber2 = document.getElementById('outInput2').value;
    if(inputNumber > textNumber > inputNumber2){
        text.classList.add('hide');
    }
})
```

```css
.first.hide{
    display: none;
}
.first{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
    <div class="first">Заработная плата 100$</div>
    <form>
    <input type='number' name="" id="outInput" placeholder="10">
    <input type="number" name="" id="ourInput2" placeholder="100">
    <button class="btnForm" type="button"> Получаем</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: что такое "псевдоэлемент hide" ?

Comment: сори за некорректный вопрос..

Answer (score 1):

```js
const textNumber = parseInt(document.querySelector('.first').textContent.match(/\d+/));
const text = document.querySelector('.first');
document.querySelector('.btnForm').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    const inputNumber = document.getElementById('outInput').value;
    const inputNumber2 = document.getElementById('outInput2').value;
    if(inputNumber > textNumber && textNumber > inputNumber2){
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        text.classList.add('hide');
    }
})
```

```css
.first.hide{
    display: none;
}
.first{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">Заработная плата 100$</div>
    <form>
    <input type='number' name="" id="outInput" placeholder="10">
    <input type="number" name="" id="outInput2" placeholder="100">
    <button class="btnForm" type="button"> Получаем</button>
    </form>
```

Замечу, что в html была ошибка и была `ourInput2` а не `outInput2`

Comment: спасибо, все исправила, но условный оператор работает только при одном больше или меньше.. если в условие и больше и меньше одновременно не работает...

Comment: что значит и больше  и  меньше одновременно?   я не знаю какие там должны быть условия.... суть в том, что эти условия надо прописывать либо через `&&` (И) либо через `||` (ИЛИ)